# EF core one-to-many relationships HasOne().WithMany() vs HasMany().WithOne()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Let's say I have the following 2 models:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I want to configure the models relationships in DbContext is there any difference between:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts);
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Posts)
            .WithOne(p => p.blog);
```

and if there is a diffrence, what is it? should I write both or just one of them?

**As a side note:** Do I have to define foreign keys? Based on my knowledge about databases, you can't create relationships without foreign keys but EF doesn't require you to have foreign key fields. So how does EF handles relationships without knowing foreign keys? Does it cause performance drops or bugs?

Comment: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration#inverse-navigation-property might be helpful today

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right, you can create relations in DbContext without foreign keys in database.

Also:

**WithOne**: *One to one relationships have a reference navigation property on both sides. They follow the same conventions as one-to-many relationships, but a unique index is introduced on the foreign key property to ensure only one dependent is related to each principal.*

**Many-to-many**: *relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.*

You only need to define one relation, because in some cases you'll create a relation for parent-child without navigation properties (one or collection).

For your example: you add a relation for Blog -> Posts because you have navigation properties in both objects, the two lines make the same but in different way:

- Blog -> Posts (Parent -> child)
- Posts -> Blog (Child -> Parent)

Comment: so are you saying there is no difference between the 2 methods and either way i can use models the same way? but using HasOne().WithMany is better?

Comment: In this case there isn't a better way, they are just different way to create the relation between two objects, usually the mapping it would be from child to parent

Comment: "You can create relations in DbContext without foreign keys in database." This is not correct. EF will introduce a shadow property which won't be in your model, but will be in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, anyway I mean from application side we don't caere about if there is a constraint in database for that relation, sometimes there are people who asking about if we need to define first the relation from database side

Comment: @H.Herzl I'm afraid EFCore does make the assumption that there's always a constraint in the database, because when one configures a relationship using .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade), the behavior only takes care of tracked dependent entities, while untracked are just supposed to be magically taken care of by a cascade-delete foreign key.
See this article and take note of the comments below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete
IMO, it was a very myopic design decision to have an ORM impose certain expectations upon database structure and constraints.

Comment: For feature request for many-to-many without needing to use an entity class for the join table see "Discussion on many-to-Many relationships (without CLR class for join table)" https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368

Answer (score 4):

You can define your models without a foreign key property. However, Entity Framework will introduce a shadow property, which will be in the database.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships):

> While it is recommended to have a foreign key property defined in the dependent entity class, it is not required. If no foreign key property is found, a shadow foreign key property will be introduced with the name `<navigation property name><principal key property name>` (see [Shadow Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) for more information).

Comment: It won't be "in the database", but rather in the entity definition in EF Core.

Comment: It will certainly be in the database. Again, according to the documentation: `Shadow properties are useful when there is data in the database that should not be exposed on the mapped entity types. They are most often used for foreign key properties, where the relationship between two entities is represented by a foreign key value in the database, but the relationship is managed on the entity types using navigation properties between the entity types.`

Comment: Shadow properties are an Entity Framework concept, not a database concept.  So no, they are not "in the database."  I mention this only for clarity for anyone researching this topic.

Comment: Actually, if you try the example on the EF Core documentation linked in my previous comment, you'll find that EF will create a column `BlogId` 'in the database' on table `Posts`. Maybe we're talking about a different thing, but the shadow property will definitely have a corresponding column in the database.

Comment: I believe "shadow property" means you won't see the property on the type itself. But it will be there in the database.